# Insert Data into data base at the end of each day

Tags: php, highcharts

I am writing a PHP application and I got a query that fetch data from my database on daily bases, but I want to Insert this data ONCE only at the end of the day, to keep the record.

Ps. This data is displayed using HighCharts.

Query:

```
    class Stats{

        public function con()
        {
            require_once('connect.php');
            $DB = new dbConnect();
            return $DB->connect();
        }

        public function getToday($user){

                $user = "SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE ott_email='$user'";
                $query = mysqli_query($this->con(), $user);
                $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

                if($count == 1){

                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                     $id = $row['user_id'];
                 }

                $today = "SELECT COUNT(tbl_template_log.user_id) FROM tbl_template_log ";
                $today .= "WHERE tbl_template_log.user_id='$id'";
                $today .= " AND DATE(send_date) = DATE(NOW())";
                $query_today = mysqli_query($this->con(), $today);
                $result = mysqli_fetch_row($query_today);

                echo $result[0];
            }

        }
    }

$stats_today = new Stats();
$stats_today->getToday($_SESSION['user']);
```

Could someone suggest a solution or some tips please, thx

Comment: Try either CRON or SQL's event scheduler.

Comment: any chance to do this without CRON....?

Comment: There are a few other ways (which popped up in another question today), but beyond the scope of my knowledge to elaborate on them. One of which I think is a daemon. Yet the event scheduler could work; that's not CRON, but cron-like.

Comment: OK thank you for your answer, I will look into CRON  and SSQL event scheduler, Do you have a link to the related question that popped out today by any chance..? thank you.

Comment: You're welcome and no I don't.